# How to configure Swagger/Swashbuckle custom serializer IControllerConfiguration ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a WebAPI endpoint that implements two different versions of the API (legacy and new).  The legacy endpoints use a specific Serializer that has all objects serialized as lower case words with underscores, the v2 endpoint uses camel cased property names.  For example, V1 = "document_type" and V2 = "documentType"

This is currently achieved using controller specific attributes to define the serialization, like so:

```
public class CamelCaseControllerConfiguration : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    }
}
```

This all works fine when called from a client via REST, but the documentation generated by Swagger always shows the property names using the legacy serializer settings.  Any suggestions on configuring swashbuckle to serialize each version properly?

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know swagger use first `Formatters` settings that can find. so if you use this:

```
controllerSettings.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() } });
```

your documentation generated by Swagger will be fine. 
swagger is a very good library and i hope they can fix this problem soon.